# Azure Function app error: The current processor architecture is: X86. The module 'AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64

Tags: azure, azure-functions, identity

I try to get all the users from AAD in an Azure function as in [this][1] tutorial but get the error:

The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.

run.ps1

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$allUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

requirements.psd1

```
# This file enables modules to be automatically managed by the Functions service.
# See https://aka.ms/functionsmanageddependency for additional information.
#
@{
    # For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. 
    # To use the Az module in your function app, please uncomment the line below.
    'Az.Accounts' = '2.5.4'
    'AzureAD' = '2.*'
}
```

I'm using PowerShell 7 and a managed identity in the Azure function. The managed identity has read permissions as in printscreen below.

[image: managed identity permissions]

I try to run the Azure function and expected a list with all AAD users. I got this log with some errors and warning:

[This is a printscreen of the first error][2]

[When I scroll down I see a second error][3]

````
Exception             : 
    Type                           : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
    SerializedRemoteException      : System.InvalidOperationException: The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
    SerializedRemoteInvocationInfo : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
    ErrorRecord                    : 
        Exception             : 
            Type                           : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
            SerializedRemoteException      : System.InvalidOperationException: The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
            SerializedRemoteInvocationInfo : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
            ErrorRecord                    : 
                Exception             : 
                    Type                           : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
                    SerializedRemoteException      : System.InvalidOperationException: The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
                    SerializedRemoteInvocationInfo : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
                    ErrorRecord                    : 
                        Exception             : 
                            Type                           : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
                            SerializedRemoteException      : System.InvalidOperationException: The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
                            SerializedRemoteInvocationInfo : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
                            ErrorRecord                    : 
                                Exception             : 
                                    Type                           : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
                                    SerializedRemoteException      : System.InvalidOperationException: The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
                                    SerializedRemoteInvocationInfo : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
                                    ErrorRecord                    : …
                                    Message                        : The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
                                    HResult                        : -2146233087
                                TargetObject          : C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1
                                CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\home\data\Manage….2.182\AzureAD.psd1:String) [Import-Module], InvalidOperationException
                                FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidProcessorArchitecture,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
                            Message                        : The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
                            HResult                        : -2146233087
                        TargetObject          : C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1
                        CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\home\data\Manage….2.182\AzureAD.psd1:String) [Import-Module], InvalidOperationException
                        FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidProcessorArchitecture,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
                    Message                        : The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
                    HResult                        : -2146233087
                TargetObject          : C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1
                CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\home\data\Manage….2.182\AzureAD.psd1:String) [Import-Module], InvalidOperationException
                FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidProcessorArchitecture,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
            Message                        : The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
            HResult                        : -2146233087
        TargetObject          : C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1
        CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\home\data\Manage….2.182\AzureAD.psd1:String) [Import-Module], InvalidOperationException
        FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidProcessorArchitecture,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
    Message                        : The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
    HResult                        : -2146233087
TargetObject          : C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1
CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\home\data\Manage….2.182\AzureAD.psd1:String) [Import-Module], InvalidOperationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidProcessorArchitecture,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
ErrorDetails          : Failure from remote command: Import-Module -Name 'AzureAD': The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
InvocationInfo        : 
    MyCommand        : Import-Module
    ScriptLineNumber : 6
    OffsetInLine     : 1
    HistoryId        : 1
    ScriptName       : C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1
    Line             : Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell
                       
    PositionMessage  : At C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1:6 char:1
                       + Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell
                       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    PSScriptRoot     : C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers
    PSCommandPath    : C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1
    InvocationName   : Import-Module
    CommandOrigin    : Internal
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1: line 6
PipelineIterationInfo : 




2023-12-28T12:47:57Z   [Information]   OUTPUT: 
2023-12-28T12:48:00Z   [Warning]   The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'Get-AzureADUser' command definition. If this command belongs to a module available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7. For more details, see https://aka.ms/functions-powershell-managed-dependency. If the module is installed but you are still getting this error, try to import the module explicitly by invoking Import-Module just before the command that produces the error: this will not fix the issue but will expose the root cause.
2023-12-28T12:48:00Z   [Error]   ERROR: The term 'Get-AzureADUser' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Exception             : 
    Type        : System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException
    ErrorRecord : 
        Exception             : 
            Type    : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException
            Message : The term 'Get-AzureADUser' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
                      Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
            HResult : -2146233087
        TargetObject          : Get-AzureADUser
        CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureADUser:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
        FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
        InvocationInfo        : 
            ScriptLineNumber : 8
            OffsetInLine     : 13
            HistoryId        : 1
            ScriptName       : C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1
            Line             : $allUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True
                               
            PositionMessage  : At C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1:8 char:13
                               + $allUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True
                               +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            PSScriptRoot     : C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers
            PSCommandPath    : C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1
            InvocationName   : Get-AzureADUser
            CommandOrigin    : Internal
        ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1: line 8
    CommandName : Get-AzureADUser
    TargetSite  : 
        Name          : LookupCommandInfo
        DeclaringType : System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.2.13.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
        MemberType    : Method
        Module        : System.Management.Automation.dll
    Message     : The term 'Get-AzureADUser' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
                  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    Data        : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
    Source      : System.Management.Automation
    HResult     : -2146233087
    StackTrace  : 
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandInfo(String commandName, CommandTypes commandTypes, SearchResolutionOptions searchResolutionOptions, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext.CreateCommand(String command, Boolean dotSource)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.AddCommand(PipelineProcessor pipe, CommandParameterInternal[] commandElements, CommandBaseAst commandBaseAst, CommandRedirection[] redirections, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
TargetObject          : Get-AzureADUser
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureADUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
InvocationInfo        : 
    ScriptLineNumber : 8
    OffsetInLine     : 13
    HistoryId        : 1
    ScriptName       : C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1
    Line             : $allUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True
                       
    PositionMessage  : At C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1:8 char:13
                       + $allUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True
                       +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    PSScriptRoot     : C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers
    PSCommandPath    : C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1
    InvocationName   : Get-AzureADUser
    CommandOrigin    : Internal
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\home\site\wwwroot\GetAllAadGroupMembers\run.ps1: line 8

2023-12-28T12:48:00Z   [Information]   OUTPUT: Account   SubscriptionName TenantId                             Environment
2023-12-28T12:48:00Z   [Information]   OUTPUT: -------   ---------------- --------                             -----------
2023-12-28T12:48:00Z   [Information]   OUTPUT: MSI@50342 azt101nsub0000   7c942460-5c3c-4314-8894-f4f09e5dd09b AzureCloud
2023-12-28T12:48:00Z   [Information]   OUTPUT: 
2023-12-28T12:48:00Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.GetAllAadGroupMembers' (Succeeded, Id=aebec362-b245-4636-b253-25cba1c10d4e, Duration=3531ms)```


  [1]: https://github.com/brettmillerb/azureadFunction/tree/main
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3H5W.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAyzX.png
````

Comment: Please make this changes in your function app: Function App> Configuration > General Settings > Platform > 64 Bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The current processor architecture is: X86. The module
> 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2312280958333475556.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.

To resolve this error, you need to update the below settings in Function App.

```
Function App> Configuration > General Settings > Platform > 64 Bit
```

[image]

I am using the below code.

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell
Connect-AzureAD
$allUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

**Output**-

[image]

Comment: did you get also users in variable $allUsers ? Or is it empty? And are you sure "Connect-AzureAD" should work without parameters?